# Thoughts on why I'm getting an error creating an index

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c

I'm trying to create an index in **Oracle 12c** and I keep getting an error

I have ensured that DOCUSER has Create Sequence and Create Table, I've also tried creating this index logged in as SYS. I've also check tomake sure that there was a column named "TRACK_DT" in the PDF_TRACKER table

```
CREATE INDEX DOCUSER.TRACK_DT_TRACKER ON DOCUSER.PDF_TRACKER (TRACK_DT) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

> ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
>   ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-10509: invalid text column: TRACK_DT
>   ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 171 ORA-06512: at
>   "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 316

Comment: I figured out the issue, it wasn't liking that the column was of the "Date" datatype. Now to see if the Developer fixes the code to index from a "DATE" datatype or not

Comment: Why are you trying to create an Oracle Text index on a date column?  That doesn't seem sensible.  If you just want a normal b-tree index on a date column, omit the `indextype is ctxsys.context`.  If you really want an Oracle Text index on a date, please explain the business problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm just running the code that the developers I work with give me. 1 of them came to me having the above issue and I was trying to figure it out, finally realizing that you can't text index a date column. she's now trying to change the datatype to timestamp and going to try the same thing.

Comment: A text index on a timestamp isn’t going to work any better.  You almost certainly want a nice, standard b-tree index not a Text index